# How to always show the full class name in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

When I hover or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + hover a class property in PhpStorm, the IDE sometimes displays the full class name:

[image: Full class name]

But sometimes only displays the short class name:

[image: Short class name]

**How can I configure PhpStorm to always display the fully qualified class name?**

Comment: It's not configurable, the way it's presented depends on where the property type is located. But why do you need it? You can chedk the namespace at `Declared in`, and you can copy reference with a shortcut.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I need it to quickly identify the type of the object. I have two `User` objects: an entity and a DTO. When refactoring stuff, I need to be able to quickly identify which one I'm dealing with. The way it is now, as a I understand it, is that it depends on where the property is *located*, not *used*, which is confusing when you look at the property from many different contexts. IMO consistency is key here, it should always display the FQCN, no matter where the property is located or used. This is what's most useful.

Comment: Please submit this as a usability issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI&c=Type%20Usability%20Problem).

Comment: Done here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56551